# ISO8601 Date Parsing ignoring Offset

Tags: java, date, java-time

I'm trying to parse `2009-07-30T16:10:36+06:00` to a date using `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXXXX`.

However the output I get appears to have not factored in the offset, as I get `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXXXX`.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

```
final DateTimeFormatter iso8601Formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXXXX");
final ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2009-07-30T16:10:36+06:00", iso8601Formatter);
final String formatted = zonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Comment: You don't need to define your own `DateTimeFormatter` for ISO-8601 dates. Use the predefined `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` or `ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME` instead.

Comment: Your code outputs `30/07/2009 16:10:36` for me, which seems correct. What value do you expect?

Comment: @TiiJ7 whatever the offset is set to the, the date is printed the same.

Comment: @Jesper yes I am aware of this - but it was a minimised example of my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding is correct you should set the `zone` similar to `withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"))`

```
final ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2009-07-30T16:10:36+06:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);

System.out.println("Without ZoneId: " + zonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")));
System.out.println("With ZoneId:    " + zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")));
```

Result

```
Without ZoneId: 30/07/2009 16:10:36
With ZoneId:    30/07/2009 10:10:36
```

Answer (score 1):

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2009-07-30T16:10:36+06:00");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(odt.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC);
// 2009-07-30T10:10:36Z
```

First you have no zoned date time, which would also depend on the country.

Then actually you want the Greenwich time, the UTC.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the time in UTC (which is not clear from the question), then the other answers give you the correct result. Since there is no time zone (such as Europe/London Pacific/Rarotonga) in your data, there is no point in using a `ZonedDateTime`. `OffsetDateTime` is a better fit:

```
    final OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2009-07-30T16:10:36+06:00");
    final OffsetDateTime utcDateTime = dateTime.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    final String formatted = utcDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    System.out.println(formatted);
```

> 30/07/2009 10:10:36